# applescript to close pdf window

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript

I have an applescript that looks like this:

```
repeat
   tell application "Adobe Reader"
     open "filepath/name.pdf"
    end tell

    delay (60)

   tell application "Adobe Reader"
     open "filepath/name1.pdf"
    end tell

    delay (60)

   tell application "Adobe Reader"
     open "filepath/name2.pdf"
    end tell

    delay (60)

end repeat
```

I want to be able to close pdf windows after they have been opened.  The issue is that these pdfs reside on a share and users have the ability to update them.  The script will only display the updated pdf if it is stopped and restarted.  I do not want to have to do this manually.  How can I do this?

Comment: Closing a window should be easy. "window 1" is usually the front (active) window so "close window 1" should close that (or "tell window 1 to close"). If you do that and the window closes, the next window gets to be "window 1" (if there is one) and so on.

Comment: Why do you do this in Adobe Reader? Don't you think that Preview is easier to script?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, which makes Preview scriptable and then continues to open and close a file of your choice.

```
-- http://www.macworld.com/article/1053391/previewscript.html
on addAppleScriptFeatures()
  try
    tell application "Finder"
      set the Preview_app to (application file id "com.apple.Preview") as alias
    end tell
    set the plist_filepath to the quoted form of ¬
      ((POSIX path of the Preview_app) & "Contents/Info")
    do shell script "defaults write " & the plist_filepath & space ¬
      & "NSAppleScriptEnabled -bool YES" with administrator privileges
    do shell script "chmod -R 755 " & the quoted form of (POSIX path of the Preview_app) with administrator privileges
    return true
  on error myErr number MyNr
    display dialog myErr & " (" & MyNr & ")." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" with icon 0
    return false
  end try
end addAppleScriptFeatures

if addAppleScriptFeatures() then
  set f to choose file
  tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open f
    delay 5 -- short for testing
    close window 2
  end tell
end if
```